# DataFormatException: incorrect header check in java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream

Tags: java, webview, javafx, deflate, inflate

I use javafx WebView in my project and it began crash at one website.
Through debug i understood, that when page receives part of js-code server uses header "Content-Encoding:deflate", ignoring my request headers.
Main problem in inflate method of InflaterInputStream.

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: incorrect header check
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
```

I reproduced this error in simple method:

```
  public byte[] makeTestRequest(String url) throws Exception {

    InputStreamResponseListener listener = new InputStreamResponseListener();
    Request request = httpClient
      .newRequest(url);
    request.send(listener);

    Response response = listener.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    byte[] uncompressedData = new byte[65536];

    if (response.getStatus() == 200) {
      try(InputStream responseContent = listener.getInputStream()){
        InputStream stream = new InflaterInputStream(responseContent);
        int len, offset = 0;
        while ((len = stream.read(uncompressedData , offset, uncompressedData.length-offset))>0) {
            offset += len;
        }
        stream.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    return uncompressedData;
  }
```

Error occurs in this method. 
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/zip/Inflater.java#247

Inflator's buffer in this moment contains data:

```
[-52, 93, 105, 115, 19, -57, -70, -2, 43, 42, 127, -54, -87, -63, -55, 116, -49, -98, 111, 22, 96, 98, -57, -40, -114, 23, -74, -101, -5, -63, 24, -127, 29, -37, -40, 120, 97, 75, -91, -54, 24, 8, -71, 5, 9, 107, 78, 40, 3, 33, 108, 39, 124, 57, 39, 62, 24, -127, -15, 34, -2, -62, -24, 31, -35, 126, -33, 30, 75, -45, -45, 61, 51, 26, 105, 20, 83, -87, 20, -42, 72, -74, -34, -18, -89, -33, 125, -23, -17, 59, -26, -58, -58, -89, 74, -117, 71, 74, -13, 11, -109, -77, 103, 59, -66, 116, 40, -47, 109, 87, -73, -68, 125, 29, -89, -25, 103, 103, 106, -49, 117, -10, 122, 108, 124, 113, 118, 126, -95, -10, -56, -78, 108, -41, -13, 8, -75, -10, 117, 44, -52, -51, -50, 47, 46, 116, 124, -7, 63, -33, 119, 76, -98, -22, -8, -110, 24, -122, 109, -17, 99, 127, 122, -66, 116, 118, -79, 7, 30, -20, -21, -104, -102, 60, -53, 126, -24, 88, 40, -99, -103, 97, 15, 59, -40, -17, -80, 95, 25, -104, 63, 85, -102, 103, 79, 53, -83, 83, -45, 14, -112, -2, 18, 123, 126, 118, 108, -90, -60, 30, -7, 47, -85, 87, -85, 43, -2, 127, -3, -118, -65, -11, 121, -63, 95, -83, 94, -59, -97, 55, 11, -2, 29, -1, -91, -65, -38, -15, -61, -66, -32, -69, -22, 127, 26, -120, -112, -1, -80, -6, 79, -42, 126, -97, -102, 54, -11, -62, -76, -102, -87, -76, -114, 107, -102, 123, -48, -103, 10, -3, -31, -25, 126, -39, -33, 97, -1, 109, 84, -81, 48, 90, 31, 51, 90, -33, -79, 127, 95, 86, 111, 85, 127, -87, -34, -16, -53, -43, 101, 124, -2, -112, 125, -7, -102, -65, -59, 62, 117, -69, -10, -11, 102, 10, -7, -29, -22, 111, -87, 47, -33, 51, 28, 51, 59, -7, 93, 90, 118, -14, -1, -12, 55, -128, -8, -6, 87, 59, -60, -10, -78, -94, 60, 114, -48, -42, 15, -57, -94, -4, 79, 32, -124, -3, -5, -100, -67, 126, -29, -81, 85, -105, 25, 73, -1, -57, 8, -72, -30, 111, -78, 47, 47, 23, -4, 109, -10, 112, -123, -47, 20, -94, -62, -16, 44, 43, 76, -123, -95, -96, 98, -66, 116, -122, 29, 89, 120, -41, 54, -115, 40, 81, 68, -45, 102, -12, -119, -109, 33, -94, -18, -78, 111, -127, -81, 44, -121, 72, -5, -61, -81, 84, -81, -80, -89, 12, 60, -10, -22, 25, -37, -93, -113, -80, 51, -80, 35, -2, -70, -65, 86, -93, -57, 72, 1, -108, 36, 125, 79, 125, 85, -90, 103, -89, -82, 74, 90, -58, 56, -79, -10, -89, 44, -29, 87, -1, 13, 35, -70, 2, -80, 50, -46, -73, 16, -8, -73, 8, 55, -20, -7, -57, 78, 98, -121, 118, -106, -70, 70, -104, 6, -102, 74, -125, -50, -74, 82, 100, -71, 87, -64, -77, 64, -125, -1, 1, -72, -104, -67, 126, 84, 103]
```

I'm surprised, but my that page successfully displayed in Chrome and Safari, but don't work in javafx WebView.
Is it a bug in inflate method or i'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It didn't solve the problem with javafx WebView, but using `Inflator` constructor with `nowrap` option helped with `incorrect header check" error`:

```
Inflator inf = new Inflator(true);
InputStream stream = new InflaterInputStream(responseContent, inf);
```