# Loading JSON in browser works, in Android it's garbage

Tags: android, json, android-volley

So I'm trying to load this JSON in Android from [here](https://www.durinsmine.com:9119/live_stats), and have tried both Volley and regular HTTP requests. The page (eventually) loads fine as UTF-8 JSON and it looks fine. However, in android, I get garbage like this:

[image]

Checked the document.characterSet, it's UTF-8.

Example as Volley (trimmed out some code, so brackets may not be exact):

```
final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError ex) {
            Log.e("LOG", ex.toString());
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Example as regular HTTP GET:

```
 HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(2500 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();

            String UTF8 = "UTF-8";
            int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), UTF8), BUFFER_SIZE);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            br.close();

            String jsonString = sb.toString();

            urlConnection.disconnect();
            urlConnection = null;

            br = null;
            sb = null;

            if (jsonString != null &&
                    jsonString.length() > 0) {

                return new JSONObject(jsonString);
            }
```

Both give garbage responses. What am I missing? I'm able to access other data on other sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is compressed using zlib. See header:

```
Content-Encoding: deflate
```

You'll have to read the raw bytes and decompress them before attempting to parse as JSON. Looks like Android provides native support for zlib via the [Deflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/Deflater.html) class.

Note that further, readers by default use the system default character encoding. Unless your system default happens to match that of the delivered content, you'll need to tell the system how to decode the charset. The correct thing is to read raw bytes from a stream, then turn the bytes into a string using the proper character encoding,

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int c;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

while ((c = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
  baos.write(buffer, 0, c);
}

String json = new String(baos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8"); // assuming the encoding if UTF-8
```

You can either know the encoding ahead of time, or parse it from the `Content-Type` header. I looked at the response from the provided URL and it does not specify a charset, so you'll have to hardcode the known value.

EDIT: apparently you can do this with a reader, although I haven't tried it:

```
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I had tried specifying the encoding in the second example in the original post, which gives me the same results as what you posted as your example when tried. UTF-8 is what I assume it would be since the charset is determined to be that in Chrome when viewed there, but still no luck, all garbage.

Comment: Both methods give the same issues and same data - garbled question marks. Thanks for trying.

Comment: And as an ugly confirmation that there may be something else going on from viewing in browser vs using android, it doesn't load in a few network JSON viewers I downloaded from the play store either.

Comment: FWIW I tried to deflate the content using zlib on Linux and it failed with "incorrect header check". We must be missing something.

Comment: hm, interesting - it comes from this project (https://github.com/fancoder/cryptonote-universal-pool) and I guess this weekend I'll see if I can't figure where and how it's being generated and if this is feasible. Thanks again.

Comment: Based on what you put, I did find this site(http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php) and it matches the bites I'm expecting, but as you also mentioned, it won't deflate for me either.Alright, well good start, thanks!

Comment: You put me on the right track, found solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28699184/dataformatexception-incorrect-header-check-in-java-util-zip-inflaterinputstream